# How to extract data using jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
table="regions"; regions=[ {id:62, name:"Abruzzen", border:[[41.444477157568635,14.855712890625],[42.72451956605904,12.80126953125]]},{id:12, name:"Zentralschweiz", border:[[47.0306,8.395899999999983],[46.6332,8.395899999999983]]}];
```

I have the above data.I need to get it separated using jquery.I need retrieve the data from the output as id,name ,border.Can anyone help me to get it.

Comment: Seems like this is what you already have in array `regions`.

Comment: ^^ This.  Check `regions[0].id`, for example

Comment: This is an output response of jquery ajax ....while giving the region[0].id I am not getting it. When I code for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    alert(resp[i]);  It is showing the single letters starting from left.
                }

Answer (score 1):

You can call the  regions by

```
regions[0].id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery each for ex

```
 regions=[ {id:62, name:"Abruzzen", border:[[41.444477157568635,14.855712890625],[42.72451956605904,12.80126953125]]},{id:12, name:"Zentralschweiz", border:[[47.0306,8.395899999999983],[46.6332,8.395899999999983]]}];
$(regions).each(function(index,widget){
    alert('id='+widget.id);
    alert('name='+widget.name);
    alert('border='+widget.border);
});
```

if you run this you'll get all ids,name and border then you can use those data

Comment: we can do like this when region is only input but I have table="regions"; before the region array

Comment: well you split whole input by ';' and then use above said solution